# A set $I$ of isolated complex numbers such that $[0,1]\subset\{Re(z):z\in I\}$

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Is there a set $I$ of **isolated** complex numbers, such that $$[0,1]\subset\{Re(z):z\in I\},$$
where $Re(z)$ is the real part of the complex number $z$.

Comment: The quick answer is no, because every point in $[0,1]$ is a limit point of $[0,1].$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, in fact, any discrete subset $I\subset\mathbb{C}$ must be countable.  For any $i\in I$, discreteness of $I$ says that we can find an open set $U_i\subset \mathbb{C}$ such that $U_i\cap I=\{i\}$.  Inside $U_i$, we can find an open disk $V_i$ containing $i$ such that the real and imaginary parts of the center of $V_i$ as well as the radius of $V_i$ are rational numbers.  Since $V_i\cap I=\{i\}$, $V_i=V_j$ implies $i=j$.  But there can only be countably many such distinct disks $V_i$, so $I$ must be countable.  More generally, this argument shows that a discrete subset of a second-countable space must be countable.

Comment: In general abstract spaces, are isolated sets always countable ?

Comment: No.  For instance, if you give an uncountable set the discrete topology, then the entire space is isolated.

Comment: thanks, so that depends on the topology.

Comment: "Isolated sets are always countable." What if they are finite?

Comment: @Vim: presumably Eric Wofsey includes finite sets in the countable sets (as many people do).